# What's the difference between Dependent Haskell and Idris

Tags: haskell, idris, dependent-type

There is a big effort mainly from Richard Eisenberg and others to create a dependent typed Haskell. I have seen Haskell and now I am trying to learn Idris. I have seen that many things that Haskell tries to implement with dependent types,type families etc are implemented in Idris, with a way more easy for a beginner to use and understand. What will be the benefit for the Haskell community if this effort succeeds? What Haskell can do better than Idris in that domain? This is not a question about Haskell vs Idris, but I want to understand the theory behind the differences. For example Haskell uses System F. Idris uses  Quantitative Type Theory.

Comment: Well, features in Idris, no matter how well designed, don't directly benefit Haskell programmers writing Haskell programs, so the potential benefit to the Haskell community  is unrelated to Idris.  (In particular, I don't think the goal of Dependent Haskell is to do anything "better than Idris".)  As for your technical question, it seems way too broad for Stack Overflow.  Did you have a specific question about differences in the type theories?

Comment: A few years old but [Dependent Types in Haskell: Theory and Practice](https://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2016/thesis/eisenberg-thesis.pdf) contains a comparison to Idris. You also mention Quantitative Type Theory, Richard also wrote [A graded dependent type system with a usage-aware semantics](https://richarde.dev/papers/2021/grad/grad-extended.pdf) with the intent to integrate it into Dependent Haskell.

Comment: Voting to close due to lack of focus.

Comment: Thanks @Iceland_jack. You comment guided me to find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I heard Eisenberg on a podcast recorded in 2017.  He said that dependent types in were a bit painful to work with, but that they were good to have when your use case made them very valuable.  It's now six years later.  I don't know whether that has changed, but if that's still true, then maybe dependent types in Idris are not *only* easier for a *beginner* to understand.